# Correct grammar? 她对待客人很友好。

Tags: translation, grammar, usage

In an Anki deck I downloaded, the Chinese translation of "Her treatment of the guests is very friendly." is given as "她对待客人很友好。" Shouldn't it be "她对待客人**得**很友好。"?

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is correct. You don't need a "得" in this sentence.

Here I want to show you a way to maintain your express correct and beautiful.

**The key point you can check your gramma in an easy way is detecting the main branch of a sentence and then do some extensions.**

For instance:

> The main branch of "Her treatment of the guests is very
>   friendly." is "Her treatment is friendly.(她的招待是友好的。)".

**After clarify the main branch of a sentence, you can now add the details into your sentence, it's always a best way.**

The sentence now looks like:

> "Her treatment *of the guests* is *very*
>   friendly.(她*对客人的* 招待是 *很* 友好的)"

**At last, change and delete some words, which makes your expression more fluent and direct.**

> "她*对客人的* 招待是 *很* 友好的" -> "她招待客人很友好"

Step by step, a correct and beautiful Chinese sentence is created by yourself.Is it interesting?

Hope my answer helps you.

Answer (score 1):

> "她对待客人很友好。" Shouldn't it be "她对待客人得很友好。"?

- 她 (she) = subject
- 对待 (treats) = verb
- 客人 (guests) = object
- 很友好 (very friendly) = adverbial phrase for the verb 对待 (treats)

"她对待客人很友好" (she treats guests very friendly) is a simple SVO sentence. I presume you can tell it is a proper sentence if you read it carefully.

I am more concern about the fact that you don't know how to use '得'  as a verb particle that indicate the result or degree.

"她对待客人得很友好。" is incorrect use of the verb particle '得' to indicate the degree of the verb

The correct form is:

> [1. verb] + [2. 得] + [3. adverbial phrase that indicates degree] = [1. 对待] +[2. 得] +[3. 很友好]

(*it describes the degree of the verb: 'To what degree she treats guests?'-- 'To the degree of very friendly'* )

> In "她对待客人对待得很友好": [她对待客人] is the topic; [对待(**得**)很友好] is the comment
>
> 'how does she treat guests?' 'she treats guests (**to the degree of**) very friendly'

More example:

> SVO sentence: "他(S) 吃飯(V) 很快 (adv)"

~

> Topic + comment sentence: "他吃飯 (topic) + 吃得很快 (comment)"

~

> break down of '吃得很快':
>
> 吃(v): eat
>
> **得** (verb particle: **to the degree of**)
>
> 很快(adv): very fast (adverbial phrase that describes the degree of the verb)